# Rails app with Node server on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I have a rails 5 app deployed on heroku. However, the chat features of the app is built using Node.js. While the rails app deploys fine on Heroku, the node server does not get started. How do I get the node part deployed? Does heroku allow both on a single dyno?

Comment: you need to add the node/npm dyno to your app

Comment: you mean add the nodejs buildpack with the already added ruby buildpack?

Comment: no, i mean you need to add the node/npm dyno to the heroku app

Comment: I think this would require paying for more dynos, as the free account allows only one dyno..do u recommend shifting to aws or soemthing else?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple buildpacks. Here is the document that explains exactly your case https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/653